# How to display front end custom block to admin order view page

Tags: admin-panel, magento1.9.2.3

I want to echo the following block to admin order view page.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('compatibility/compatibilityblock')->setTemplate('tm/compatibility/savequote.phtml')->tohtml();
```

I have tried the following way but not worked.

```
echo $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
->createBlock('compatibility/compatibilityblock')
->setData('area','frontend')
->setTemplate('tm/compatibility/savequote.phtml')->tohtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `area` data from within the constructor of the block:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setData('area','frontend');
    $this->setTemplate('tm/compatibility/savequote.phtml');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,then how to echo this to admin view file

Comment: `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('compatibility/compatibilityblock')->toHtml()`

Comment: I did that way but not display the content of that block

Comment: add a die or something in the constructor to be sure that the code there is being executed